# Using fetch-and-add as lock

Tags: multithreading, x86, operating-system, locking, mutual-exclusion

I am trying to understand how fetch-and-add can be used as a lock. Here is what the book (OS's: 3 Easy pieces) says:

> The basic operation is pretty simple: when
>   a thread wishes to acquire a lock, it first does an atomic fetch-and-add
>   on the ticket value; that value is now considered this thread’s “turn”
>   (myturn). The globally shared lock->turn is then used to determine
>   which thread’s turn it is; when (myturn == turn) for a given thread,
>   it is that thread’s turn to enter the critical section.

What I do not understand is how the thread checks if the lock held by another process before entering the cretical seection. All I can read that the value will be incremented, no mention of checks!

Another part says:

> Unlock is accomplished
>   simply by incrementing the turn such that the next waiting thread (if
>   there is one) can now enter the critical section.

Which I can not interpret in a way where checks will not be performed, which can not be true becuase it compremises the whole porpose of locking cretical sections. What am I fmissing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I do not understand is how the thread checks if the lock held by another process before entering the cretical seection.

You need an "atomic fetch" for this, maybe something like "`while( atomic_fetch(currently_serving) != my_ticket) { /* wait */ }`".

If you have "atomic fetch and add", then you can implement "atomic fetch" by doing "atomic fetch and add the value zero", maybe something like "`while( atomic_fetch_and_add(currently_serving, 0) != my_ticket) { /* wait */ }`".

For reference; the full sequence could be something like:

```
    my_ticket = atomic_fetch_and_add(ticket_counter, 1);

    while( atomic_fetch_and_add(currently_serving, 0) != my_ticket) {
        /* wait */
    }

    /* Critical section (lock successfully acquired). */

    atomic_fetch_and_add(currently_serving, 1);   /* Release the lock */
```

Of course you might have a better atomic fetch you can use instead (e.g. for some CPUs any normal aligned load is atomic).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clarified everything I found mystical. The book did not mention that you can give parameters to it.